# When importing keras on my Raspberry Pi 4 I get the same error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, raspberry-pi

I have installed Tensorflow and all its libraries following various websites and my terminal actually tells me they are installed and have been upgraded to their last versions, but somehow when I try to run the code in Python it keeps giving me the same error. In case you were wondering the Python code itself works fine on my laptop.

The error code says as it follows:

```
tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/pi/8F3B-E71C/TRachscope/livefeed_tensorflow_model.py", line 5, in <module>
    from keras import models

  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>

    from keras import models
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 19, in <module>

    from keras import backend
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 39, in <module>

    from tensorflow.python.eager.context import get_config
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context' (/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py)**
```

Comment: Looks like you've not installed libhdfs libraries... Do you really need HDFS?

Comment: @OneCricketeer ok then I'll install those libraries. As for HDFS I don't know whether or not I need It, Could that be the problem?. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: I don't know what your code does, but if you are not using Hadoop, I don't see how you could get a `HadoopFileSystem load error`

Comment: Did you install dependencies as mentioned  in this threads?                                   https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin#usage
    https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107920